# Wood Sagging on Dining Table Repair Frame - Stripped Screws

Tags: wood, furniture

I have a dining room table that is sagging where the side of the tables are, on both sides just in different areas.  What can i do to repair this? Screws are stripped from the wood. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is a lot of stripped screw hole advice on this stack.  Here is one.   https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10884/fixing-stripped-screw-in-soft-wood-door-frame   You could start by augmenting the screw holes as described in one of these answers and screwing the table back together.