# How do I reduce the size of screw holes for a door hinge, where door is hollow?

Tags: wood, hole-repair

This image shows one of the hinges on a hollow door that's correctly affixed.

[image: hinge]

I just discovered this hidden at the bottom of a door that's held on by 3 hinges like this so it wasn't impacting the door. One screw is missing and the other is obviously not the original screw. The holes have become too big to hold the screws. I was planning on buying a couple of the correctly sized screws but how do I reduce the size of those holes?

[image: hinge]

Update #1: The linked (possible duplicate) question deals with a solid wood door. This is a hollow core door so those solutions won't work. My mistake that I didn't specify this in the original question.

Update #2: I estimate that the thickness of wood that I'm dealing with is about 3/16" so there is very little wood to work with here because it's a hollow core door.

Comment: insert toothpick, and use #10 screw

Comment: Common way is using toothpicks/wooden matches and wood glue.  Fill hole with glue and tooth picks and let dry.  Cut any wood sticking out of hole.

Comment: @crip659 that's a very good answer

Comment: I agree it should be an answer.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5729/how-do-i-rehang-a-wooden-door-with-worn-screw-holes

Comment: The correct screw to use is the short one on the left, its sloped head will fit the hinge hole nicely and prevent the hinge from moving. But obviously, you will need a longer one for old screw hole that tended to be larger due to repeat operations. I'll take the hinge to the hardware store and find/ask for the correct screw rather than filling the hole, as it will getting loose again and again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Common way is using toothpicks/wooden matches and wood glue. Fill hole with glue and tooth picks and let dry. Cut any wood sticking out of hole with a knife.  Drill pilot hole and will be able to use proper screws again.
Can also drill out holes to fit small wood dowels attached with glue, but more work.

Comment: I just added 2 updates to the question to clarify further. My apologies for not stating those facts at the outset. It is a hollow core door. Based on this new information do you feel that there is one solution that is better than the other? There is very little wood to work with here.

Comment: Hollow core doors usually have solid wood around the edges(about an inch deep), especially for hinge and door knob sides.  Both will still work.  3/16" is just the covering wood.  3/16 would not hold screws for hinges well.

Comment: I checked with a flashlight. These doors don't look like they were made like they should have been. I would have absolutely expected what you described but this is 3/16 thick right where the hinge goes in.